# How would I find the height that the ball rebounds? I found impulse, but I don't know what to do with it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

A ball (1.5kg) falls from rest from a height of 2 meters. When the ball hits the ground, it experiences a 1500 N force upwards for 0.01 seconds. To what height will the ball rebound? (How high will the ball bounce back up)

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the velocity the instant the ball hits the ground using

$$v_f^2 = v_i^2 + 2gh$$

You have the impulse which is given by

$$F\Delta t = m\Delta v$$

This means you can actually calculate the change in momentum. The change in momentum is obviously $m(v_f - v_i)$.

You should be able to do the rest.

Good luck!